# Postgres trigger function for check constraint with if statement

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that looks like the one below. I am trying to add a constraint that will not allow for sires to be added if they have "sex" as "f" and dams if they have "sex" as "m". I read up on trigger functions and function creation in general but still can't figure out how exactly to write a function that would work for this constraint.
My latest attempt is below, but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_sex() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF dam NOT IN (SELECT sheep_id
       FROM sheep
       WHERE sex='f'
      )
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'only females can be dams';
   END IF;
 
   RETURN dam;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER sex_trigger_f BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sheep FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION check_sex();
```

````
    Column     |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
---------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 sheep_id      | integer               |           | not null | nextval('sheep_sheep_id_seq'::regclass)
 tag_id        | character varying(10) |           | not null |
 sex           | character varying(1)  |           | not null |
 dob           | date                  |           | not null |
 purchase_date | date                  |           |          |
 breed_id      | bigint                |           | not null |
 sire          | bigint                |           |          |
 dam           | bigint                |           |          |
Indexes:
    "sheep_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (sheep_id)
    "sheep_tag_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (tag_id)
Check constraints:
    "sex_vals" CHECK (sex::text = ANY (ARRAY['f'::character varying, 'm'::character varying]::text[]))
Foreign-key constraints:
    "sheep_breed_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (breed_id) REFERENCES breeds(id)
    "sheep_self_fk" FOREIGN KEY (sire) REFERENCES sheep(sheep_id)
    "sheep_self_fk_dam" FOREIGN KEY (dam) REFERENCES sheep(sheep_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "sheep" CONSTRAINT "sheep_self_fk" FOREIGN KEY (sire) REFERENCES sheep(sheep_id)
    TABLE "sheep" CONSTRAINT "sheep_self_fk_dam" FOREIGN KEY (dam) REFERENCES sheep(sheep_id)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_sex() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
DECLARE
    sex_type_dam varchar;
    sex_type_sire varchar;
$$
BEGIN
  
    SELECT INTO sex_type_dam sex FROM sheep WHERE sheep_id = NEW.dam;

    IF FOUND THEN
        IF sex_type_dam != 'f' THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'only females can be dams';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    SELECT INTO sex_type_sire sex FROM sheep WHERE sheep_id = NEW.sire;

    IF FOUND THEN
        IF sex_type_sire != 'm' THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'only males can be sires';
        END IF;
    END IF;
 
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

`FOUND` is a special variable from here [Result status](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) that will be true if there is a value selected into the `sex_type_*` variable. This means the case where `dam` or `sire` has no value will be ignored. If they do have a value and a `sex` value is returned then it will tested to see if it is the correct sex. If it is not then an exception will be raised otherwise the entire `NEW` record will be returned.

Comment: This makes sense. However, what should I return in this function?

Comment: See updated answer. It is explained here [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) in section starting, 'Row-level triggers fired BEFORE ...'

Comment: Alright a complete function that combines your solution and mine.